# What do I need to do to pass value as attribute from angular template to directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a directive that looks like this:

```
<g-map-locations center={{myLocation}} zoom="4" id="map" class="map"></g-map-locations>
```

The zoom-value is used in angular to set the zoom for a google map:

```
attrs.zoom = zoom
setMapOptions: function(center, zoom){
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: center
    }
    return mapOptions;
},
```

google maps complain that `setZoom: is not a number`, though it works i do

```
zoom = 4
```

Can I tell angular to pass the value as a number or convert it in the directive somehow?

Comment: try  { zoom: parseInt(zoom), ....

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes are passed in as strings, save for when they are passed in as scoped objects and parsed. The easiest solution, in my view, would be to parse the the number as integer:

```
setMapOptions: function(center, zoom){
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: parseInt(zoom, 10),
        center: center
    }
    return mapOptions;
}
```